# How do I query a Drupal Shortcut (8.x/9.x) by its URL or Menu Path?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

We're rolling out an update to an in-house Drupal installation profile, and one of the menu paths that is used frequently is getting changed. Most of our installations reference that menu path in a shortcut (via the "Shortcut" module in core). In an update hook, we'd like to be able to query for those shortcuts and update them.

It feels like this should be straightforward, but for some reason we're finding it difficult to query for shortcuts by their url. We can query them by title, but that seems fragile (since the title could be different between installations, might be different by localization, etc.).

We tried the following, but this lead to the error message `'link' not found`:

```php
// This does NOT work.
$shortcuts_needing_update = 
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('shortcut')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'link' => [
        'internal:/admin/timeline-management',
      ],
    ]);

// This works, but is fragile.
$shortcuts_needing_update = 
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('shortcut')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'title' => 'My shortcut',
    ]);
```

Based on the code in `\Drupal\shortcut\Entity\Shortcut::baseFieldDefinitions()` and `\Drupal\shortcut\Controller\ShortcutSetController::addShortcutLinkInline()` it's obvious that Shortcut entities have a property called `link` that can be set like an array containing a `uri` key, yet it does not seem possible to query by this property even though it's a base field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the database, it appears that Drupal stores the URL in a database column called `link__uri`:

[image: The database schema for the 'shortcut_field_data' table shows that the values of the 'link' property get flattened out to columns called 'link__uri', 'link__title', and 'link__options']

TL;DR That means that this works:

```
$shortcuts_needing_update = 
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('shortcut')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'link__uri' => 'internal:/admin/old/path',
    ]
  );
```

Read on if you want to know the subtle reason why this is the case.

Drupal's database layer uses pluggable "table mapping" objects to tell it how to map an entity (like a Shortcut) to one or more database tables and database table columns. The logic for generating a column name for a field looks like this in the default table mapping (`\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping`):

[image: The contents of the '\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping::getFieldColumnName()' method (described below).]

As shown above, if a field indicates it allows "shared" table storage, and the field has multiple properties (`uri`, `title`, etc.), then the mapping flattens the field into distinct columns for each property, prefixed by the field name. So, a Shortcut entity with `link => ['uri' => 'xyz']]` becomes the column `link__uri` with a value of `xyz` in the database.

You don't see this often with entities like nodes, which is why this seems strange here. I'm usually accustomed to seeing a separate database table for things like link fields. That's because nodes and other content entities don't usually allow shared table storage for their fields.

How does the mapping determine if a field should use shared table storage? That logic looks like this:
[image: The contents of the '\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping::allowsSharedTableStorage()' method (described below).]

So, the default table mapping will use shared table storage for a field only under specific circumstances:

1. The field can't have a custom storage handler (checks out here since shortcuts don't provide their own storage logic).
2. The field has to be a base field (shortcuts are nothing *without* a link, so that field is defined as a base field as mentioned in the OP).
3. The field has to be single-valued (checks out -- shortcuts have only one link).
4. The field must not have been deleted (checks out; again, what is a shortcut without a link field?).

This specific set of circumstances aren't often satisfied by nodes or other content entities, which is why it's a bit surprising here.

We can confirm this by using Devel PHP to ask the table mapping for shortcuts directly, with code like the following:

```php
$shortcut_table_mapping = 
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('shortcut')
    ->getTableMapping();

$efm = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
$storage_definitions = $efm->getFieldStorageDefinitions('shortcut');

$link_storage_definition = $storage_definitions['link'];

$has_dedicated_storage = $shortcut_table_mapping->requiresDedicatedTableStorage($link_storage_definition);
$link_column = $shortcut_table_mapping->getFieldColumnName($link_storage_definition, 'url');

dpm($has_dedicated_storage, 'has_dedicated_storage(link)');
dpm($link_column, 'link_column');
```

This results in the following:
[image: If you ask the table mapping configured for Shortcut entities to generate the column for the 'link' field, it confirms the name we deduced from looking at the DB schema ('link__url') is correct.]